# "PG::UndefinedColumn:" when deploying rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, database-migration

When deploying my changes to production using Capistrano I get the error

```
PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "address_id" of relation "member_applications" does not exist
```

In my migrations I have

```
class CreateAddresses < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :addresses do |t|
            t.string :full_name, null: false
            t.string :email, null: false
            t.string :phone, null: false
            t.string :address, null: false
            t.string :state, null: false
            t.string :country, null: false
            t.string :postcode, null: false
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

and

```
class CreateMemberApplications < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
    def change
        create_table :member_applications do |t|
            t.references :location, null: false
            t.references :addresses, null: false
            t.references :user, null: false
            t.string :full_name, null: false
            t.date :birthdate, null: false
            t.timestamps
        end
    end
end
```

and finally

```
class SetAddressToNull < ActiveRecord::Migration[5.1]
  def change
      change_column_null :member_applications, :address_id, true
  end
end
```

This last migration seems to be the one causing issues. What could be causing this issue? It has been working on my development machine but it has been a little while since I last deployed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the problem is here:

```
create_table :member_applications do |t|
  ...
  t.references :addresses, null: false
  ...
end
```

It should be `t.references :address, null: false` in singular.

You can check your `db/schema.rb` to verify.

Comment: That was the issue. Somehow my schema was using the correct address_id. How that managed to happen I will never know but after fixing the migration and renaming the column on the server with psql it works find now.